# Command line arguments to dockerized lagacy NET framework project while debugging with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to debug a dockerized VS2019 .NET framework solution with two console apps.

The problem is that both projects require startup arguments but neither the ENTRYPOINT of Dockerfile, or entrypoint in docker-compose.yml seem to have effect on starting debugged projects.

This is a sample of my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  ejossrv:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}ejossrv
    build:
      context: .\ejossrv
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: ["C:\\app\\bin\\Debug\\ejossrv.exe","-p","1954"]
  proksi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}proksi
    build:
      context: .\proksi
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: ["C:\\app\\bin\\Debug\\proksi.exe","-p","1954"]
  #rabbit1:
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in `com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments` property. This is a working sample:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  ejossrv:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}ejossrv
    build:
      context: .\ejossrv
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    labels:      
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments: " -p 1954"
    platform: windows
    depends_on:
      - rabbit1
  proksi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}proksi
    build:
      context: .\proksi
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    labels:      
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments: " -p 1954"
    platform: windows
    depends_on:
      - rabbit1
```